# View slows down when I add additional conditions in where clause when querying the view

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-view

I am using a similar query. I cannot post the actual query and the execution plans here. I tried adding an execution plan suggesting a non-clustered index but it slowed down the query further.
I know it's incomplete information, but can you please suggest what I can try please? I am out of options!!
I am putting the below condition in the where clause, the date seems fine but as soon as I add any of the other 2, the query takes hours. The where condition is used when I try to query the view.

```
 where Date_Time between '2021-11-01 00:00:00.000' and '2022-11-02 00:00:00.000'
  and Visit_code not in ('12', '13')
  and mode_code <>'99'
```

### [Execution plan XML](https://file:///C:/Temp/actual%20execution%20plan%20with%20all%20three%20condition.xml)

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_Test] AS
 select fields
  
  from table1 ed
  left join table2 e on ed.field1_id = e.field1_id
  left join table3 et on et.field1_id = ed.field1_id    
  left join table4 etf on etf.field1_id = e.field1_id
                            and etf.field2_cd= 85429041                                 
                            and etf.dt_tm_field >= '2025-01-01 00:00:00.0000000'
  left join table5 etf_dt on  etf_dt.field1 = e.field1
                            and etf_dt.field3= 85429039                                 
                            and etf_dt.dt_tm_field >=  '2025-01-01 00:00:00.0000000'
  left join table6 ei on ei.field1 = ed.field1
                                        and ei.field4_cd = 123485.00
    left join table7 cvo_ModeOfArrival on cvo_ModeOfArrival.field = ed.field6
                                                 and cvo_ModeOfArrival.field5 = 12345
    left join table7 cvo_ModeOfSep on cvo_ModeOfSep.field = ei.field7
                                                 and cvo_ModeOfSep.field5 = 23456
    left join table7 cvo_FinancialClass on cvo_FinancialClass.field = e.field8
                                                 and cvo_FinancialClass.field5 = 34567
    left join table7 cvo_Specialty on cvo_Specialty.field = e.field9
                                                 and cvo_Specialty.field5 = 45678
  left join table8 ea on ea.field1_id = e.field1_id
    left join table7 cvo_ea on cvo_ea.field = ea.field10
                                                 and cvo_ea.field11 = 345666
GO
```

Comment: So is that `WHERE` meant to be in your `VIEW`s definition? I *assume* that all those unqualified columns (a very bad habit) are unambiguous names and refer to `table1`?

Comment: No, they don't refer to the same table1(if you are talking about the field1_id column). Sorry for the confusion. the same id exists in different tables. It's a foreign key, hence the same name. Where is not in the view definition. Its when I try to query the view.

Comment: Is your view indexed? You've tagged indexed-view, but never mention in anywhere.

Comment: Help on performance really needs the complete table and index definitions and the actual execution plan - [pastetheplan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)

Comment: @pastetheplan I know I need to paste the plan but contains all the table details which I cannot post on a public forum. Hence just trying to get hints on what I can work on to improve it.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from doing a find/replace on the planxml before posting it.

Comment: @JamesZ I was trying to get some help on if I could create an indexed view. Hence the tag. I just removed the tag now

Comment: @Stu I have edited and tried adding the plan but somehow its not getting added. I read the links on how to do it but its too long for them to update. Can you point me to the right direction on how I can upload the XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code I can't see anything that can be improved in the context of T-SQL statement.

I will advice the following:

- check each table and which columns you need in the `fields` part - it is possible the engine to be reading the whole row, instead the needed columns as index is missing; you can create [nonclustered](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-nonclustered-indexes?view=sql-server-ver16) indexes in order to reduce the IO
- check if any of these new indexes can be [filtered](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-filtered-indexes?view=sql-server-ver16) index, as you have a lot of hard coded criteria (`ei.field4_cd = 123485.00`)

If the above is not enough, you may think of creating separate table for storing this information and populate it in advanced.

In order to debug, you can add the following line before the query:

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON;
```

and then past the results from the messages tab [here](http://statisticsparser.com/) - it will give you some details about for which tables most IO is consumed. You can start with them.

Comment: I built Non clustered indexes on almost 6-7 tables after analyzing their live statistics and execution plans and it did wonders!! The query which was taking 6 hours took 20s to finish. Thankyou so much!!

Answer (score 1):

I would investigate breaking this query into multiple parts using derived tables. There are plenty of examples for this online. I always try to use `SELECT TOP (2147483647) ...`.